# nasm detected eof, read blocks of data

Tags: assembly, nasm, system-calls

i need to read some unknown number of chars from file. I want to detected the end of string (in this case it is EOF). Firstly i read from file using syscall 3, and then checked if rax is equal to 0. Thats works well if I read one char at the same time,but I want to read like this:

```
mov rax, 3
mov rbx, stdin
mov rcx, input
mov rdx, 8
int 80h
```

So i read 8 bits, and then i got loop over this bits i want to detect if there is eof.
EOF detection looks like this::

```
cmp r8b,0
jle loop_end
```

But that doenst work at all. Can i somehow read more bits fe. 8. And detected EOF on fe position 5? Or maybe syscall 3 can return number of bits readed?

Comment: On what system are you working?  Normally in 64-bit mode you want to use the `syscall` instruction instead of `int 80h`.

Comment: The return value from the system call will be in `rax`.  A value of 0 indicates EOF, just like for `read(2)` in C.  Note that you can also get a positive value less than 8, or a negative value in case of error; your code should properly handle all these cases.

Comment: i see that for 7 letters i get rax equal to 8 (because of EOF). How can i decide if the last bit is EOF or normal number, I tried cmp last bit to 0 but it did not work. What is EOF code?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  There is no "EOF code".  `rax` contains the number of characters successfully read, pure and simple.  You have to process that number of characters.  If `rax` is zero then you have reached the end of the file and should stop reading any more.

Comment: By the way, I think everywhere in your question where it says "bits" you actually mean "bytes".  This is rather confusing.

Comment: Related: [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730) - the 32-bit ABI only works if your pointers happen to fit in 32 bits.  And also it zeros r8..r11.